# Page Content Fade In

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade

I know that this question may have been asked before but upon looking through previous questions many others seem to be asking different things, or not quite exactly what I'm looking for.

So here we go, being specific:

I'm looking to achieve a fade-in and hopefully ALSO a fade-out effect on MULTIPLE elements on a page. I'd prefer to use something very simple to achieve this.

Here are some examples:

http://vyctoire.com/project/polymn ( The better example, although subtle animation )

https://www.cedricpereira.com/modulab ( Another example, although I think this is using AJAX which isn't really what I'm looking for. )

Comment: Do you want the fade in behaviour on page scroll

Comment: There are some libraries out there to achieve this kind of effects. An example is https://scrollrevealjs.org/

Comment: @wawmsey I have tried different ways but I want to know what others thing are the most efficient/easy

Comment: @Thusitha I think so? I gave a very specific example ( vyctoire.com )
This seems very interesting! Do you have an example of this being used in a not-grid fashion?